# I'm working for templatizing email notification for prometheus. Can somebody share me some email template set for alert manager of promethius

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

I'm using default template as of now . Now I would like to create new template . Please help me by sharing how to read values from prometheus and a basic template to understand which you have used in your project